# How to stop Docker (and Kubernetes) using Docker desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop for MacOS and I don't know how to stop the Docker service. It runs all the time using up the MacBook battery.

[image]

On a simple search, there are docs showing how to stop the containers but not the docker service itself.

I might be missing something obvious, but is there a way to stop both Kubernetes and Docker service without having to kill the desktop app?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the app and the docker vm are linked. You can disable the kubernetes instance in the options.

Comment: see this [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637339/1318694) and the [resulting issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4388)

Comment: Everyone should look at Hannes Stoolmann's answer below for a working resolution to the issue. At least it worked for me on MacOS Mojave, to be  accurate.

Comment: Why would you leave docker desktop running when you can restart it any time? imo it is of no use when the docker vm is not running, therefore Quit Docker Desktop is ok (still imo).

Comment: It didn't work for me too and I found this question here. After some time I noticed the Docker icon has tooltip "Docker is stopping". All in all it took about 10 minutes for it to quit but it did.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The docker desktop app starts a qemu vm, so the desktop app has no control over the PIDs.
To overcome the "situation" do the following:

- open the Terminal app
- edit the file `~/.bash_profile`
- add the following lines

```
    #macro to kill the docker desktop app and the VM (excluding vmnetd -> it's a service)
    function kdo() {
      ps ax|grep -i docker|egrep -iv 'grep|com.docker.vmnetd'|awk '{print $1}'|xargs kill
    }
```

- save the file

Quit the terminal app and open it again.

Type `kdo` to kill all the dependend apps (hypervisor, docker daemon etc.)

Comment: This worked! After all this time of the mighty Docker team acting like it was  impossible to do anything about the issue. Hannes "first week on Stack Overflow" Stoolmann comes along and resolves it. I'll have to dive into what's going on in that function but THANKS!

Comment: @jmdeamer. No prob. The desktop app starts the VM as child process, so it should be quite easy to send a SIGNAL "down the road" ;-)

Comment: As of today's latest version you can stop DOCKER Desktop App by clicking the "ship" symbol in the top panel and then hit "Quit Docker Desktop" !

Comment: @HannesStoolmann There is no "ship" symbol? Docker Desktop 4.2.0 (70708)

Comment: There is. It depends on the OSX version. It depends where you place the panel ;-)

Comment: If you don't have 'egrep' or get a warning, you can replace it with `grep -E` instead. Example: grep -iEv 'grep|com.docker.vmnetd'

Comment: **Beware:** there's a bug preventing the Docker Desktop icon from appearing on MacOS. They have [an article on how to fix](https://www.docker.com/blog/new-docker-menu-improved-release-highlights-with-docker-desktop-4-5/).

Answer (score 27):

You can open the Activy Monitor, select Docker and then use the **Quit** button.

Maybe you will need to use the **Force Quit** option.

[image]

Comment: Using quit/force quit on com.docker.backend just resulted in it automatically restarting on my machine. The only thing that actually terminated the process was the macro Hannes Stoolmann suggested as an answer.

Comment: @jmdeamer weird, this does not happen for me, and does not make sense too, maybe is a problem with your machine or os version

Answer (score 4):

`killall Docker` # Kill all the docker related process in your MacOS

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work anymore. It worked but not it says it couldn't find any related process

Comment: Same here -- `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Answer (score 2):

I had been searching around for an answer to this too, as I noticed `com.docker.hyperkit` was taking >3GB memory and a lot of CPU, when the desktop app wasn't even opened on Mac OS X Catalina, Docker Desktop 3.0.4

Just as I was about `kill -9`, I noticed that quitting the docker app again actually *did* kill off every process except `com.docker.vmnetd` for whatever reason.

So I guess the solution here was... reopen and re-quit? I also made sure, of course, there were no running containers. I removed an old image too, unsure if that was related to it finally being able to fully quit.

Comment: Quitting appears to kill the daemon after a few seconds; just not right away.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ***official*** way:

[image]

Works for me with

```
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.1.2
BuildVersion:       23B92
```

checked with `ps` (only thing left is `docker.vmnetd`):

```bash
$ ps -eaf | grep -i docker
    0   517     1   0 18Dec23 ??         0:00.33 /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd
  501 28284 17445   0 12:28pm ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Hannes example, but with alias:
Create an `.alias`-file (in your home-dir) and add this line:

```
alias dockerstop="ps ax|grep -i docker|egrep -iv 'grep|com.docker.vmnetd'|awk '{print $1}'|xargs kill"
```

Make sure, the file is called during shell-startup (e.g. `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.zprofile` ...), like so:

```
source .aliases
```

After creating a new shell you can call the command `dockerstop`. The advantage of aliases over functions is (in my opinion), that you can easily list and filter them (e.g. `alias | grep docker`).

Answer (score 0):

`com.docker.hyperkit`  taked > 8GB Memory . just run in terminal `kill -9` `PID`

ex my process `kill -9 71397`
[image]

Comment: Never use `kill -9` unless you have separately established that a regular `kill` will not work. You are preventing the process from cleaning up after itself properly.

Comment: In this case, my docker process launched in the background, and I was forced to quit but docker was processing until I was forced to do so

Comment: There is always a way to kill a process, the problem is that the menu option Quit Docker Desktop does not do what it must.